# How to detect the last page before the header record changes

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I need to place in the header of a crystal report, the number 0 or 1.

1 if the page is the last page of the current record, else 0.

i.e I have multiple records that each have a varying number of detail lines. Each record starts on a new page with a repeating header. If the detail lines span more than one page, I need to write a 1 on the last page of the record header and a 0 on every other page header.

I've tried using the following in a formula field to detect the next record's primary key

```
iif((Next({primary_key}) = {primary_key}), '0', '1')
```

but I think this will always return 1 because it's checking the next record and not the next page's record.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the goal?  Are you trying to suppress a repeated header?

Comment: Instead of this approach it is easy if you start the `group on new page` I mean to say start the every new group value in a new page and print 1 on that page by goinig to the formula section of the `new page after`

Comment: The goal is, literally, to add text of '1' to the page header of the last page that a group spans on to - printing a '0' on every other page. The number makes up the numbers of a barcode that is required at the top of every page.